# How to send linux information to a windows local folder?

Tags: windows

Is there any way to send output of Linux to the local folder of windows?
E.g.:

```
oWShell.SendKeys ("ls /home/branch > output.txt")
oWShell.SendKeys("{ENTER}" )
```

here using `cat output.txt` --> I can see the date in the terminal window
but I want import this data into my local folder which is in windows system.
local folder: `C:\Test\Myoutput.txt`

Answer (score 0):

You should just mount the windows local folder via Samba on the linux machine and then do:

```
oWShell.SendKeys ("ls /home/branch > /windoze/local/folder/output.txt")
```

Alternatively you can use Putty's `scp` to copy the file from the remote system to your Windows machine, after running the normal ( `> output.txt`) command.